# my vba only selects tables in an active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a text to columns in one column from two different tables

The VBA code I tried only works if the sheet is active. It returns 1004 if it's not.

```
Sub TextToColumns()
' text to columns in REF from query PendingOrders

Sheets("PendingOrders").ListObjects("PendingOrders").ListColumns("REF").Range.Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range( _
        "PendingOrders[[#Headers],[REF]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
End Sub
```

One table is PendingOrders (in PendingOrders sheet), and the other table is Stock, in Stock sheet.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Writing as a comment because I am not 100% sure and can't be bothered to check, but I would assume it is because you cannot select from a sheet different than the other that is currently selected. For what's it's worth, it's almost never required to select a cell in VBA. Here, you can simply drop ".Select" and replace with the content of your next line `...ListColumns("REF").TextToColumns...`

Comment: @ApplePie, your correct, you should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume it is because you cannot select from a sheet different than the other that is currently selected. For what's it's worth, it's almost never required to select a cell in VBA. Here, you can simply drop ".Select" and replace with the content of your next line (omitting `Selection.`)

```
...ListColumns("REF").TextToColumns...
```